# If A be real orthogonal matrix then $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $A$ is real orthogonal matrix then $A^2$=$I$
Proof:If $A$ is orthogonal then $A^{2}A=I$ 
Also, $A^{-1}=A{T}$ ; ${A^{T}}^{(-1)}=A$
$A^{T}A-I=0$ permultipling by ${A^{T}}^{(-1)}$ both side

$A-{A^{T}}^{(-1)}I=0$
$A-(1/A)I=0$
$A=(1/A)$

$A^{2}=I$
Can this be proof of this ??

Comment: How do you define orthogonal

Comment: @M.Winter Exactly my thoughts.

Comment: How can this be true? Any rotation matrix is orthogonal but their square is usually not the identity.

Comment: I have a feeling he means some sort of reflection

Comment: There are some counterexamples. Think about a rotation in the plane

Comment: If $A^2A=I $ and $A^2=I $, doesn't that mean  $A=I $

Comment: @Displayname Yes it does

Answer (score 1):

No, this is generally false.

A real orthogonal matrix $A$ satisfies $A^TA=I$; if also $A^2=I$, then
$$
A^T=A^{-1}=A
$$
so $A$ is symmetric. In particular $A$ has real eigenvalues, so its eigenvalues can be just $1$ or $-1$.

Conversely, *if* an orthogonal matrix $A$ has only $1$ or $-1$ as eigenvalues, then it's true that $A^2=I$. Indeed, $A$ is diagonalizable with an orthogonal matrix (having only real eigenvalues), so $A=UDU^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal; by assumption, $D^2=I$, so the result follows.

However, an orthogonal matrix generally has complex eigenvalues. For instance the eigenvalues of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos x & -\sin x \\
\sin x & \cos x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are $\cos x+i\sin x$ and $\cos x-i\sin x$, which are not real unless $\sin x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be example $$\begin{pmatrix}cosx&-sinx\\sinx&cosx\end{pmatrix}$$ here $A^{T}A=I$ and $A^{2}=I$

Comment: In this example $A^2$ is only $I$ for $x=(2k+1)\pi,k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Why is this presented as an "answer" rather than edited into the main question? It seems it is meant to be part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is false. The rotation matrix you showed doesn't prove the result. Also, finding an example is not a proof. I can't say all odd numbers are prime just because 3 is odd and prime. This is obviously false since 15 is odd but not prime.

As pointed out in the comments, your matrix only has the property $A^2=I$ for odd multiples of $\pi$.